# Reverse matrix diagonal

Tags: python

```
d = [[11, 2, 4], [4, 5, 6], [10, 8, -12]]

d1 = []

for i in range(n):
  d1.append(arr[i][i])
```

d1 equals to `[11, 5, -12]` which is correct.

How to do a reverse matrix, I want an array with `[4, 5, 10]`

How can I do this with Python?

Comment: You have `i`, can you think of an arithmetic operation to do with it that will give you `2` when `i = 0`, `1` when `i = 1`, and `0` when `i = 2`?

Comment: `[sublist[-i] for i, sublist in enumerate(d, start=1)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in a list comprehension using enumerate on the rows to get items from last to first column:

```
d = [[11, 2, 4], [4, 5, 6], [10, 8, -12]]

d1 = [row[-i] for i,row in enumerate(d,1)]

print(d1)
[4, 5, 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do `d1.append(arr[i][n-i−1])` instead of `d1.append(arr[i][i])`.

Comment: `arr[i][-i−1]` should work